# HTTP Post request body values null c#

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm setting up a react app with a .NET Core backend. I'm sending a HTTP post request using fetch with the username value and password value to the backend c# user controller login method. The http request is below:

```
function login(username, password) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    };

    return fetch(`/user/login`, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

            return user;
        });
}
```

I can see in google dev tools that the request is being sent from the code above and contains both a username and password. I placed a breakpoint on the below code on the first line and can see the username and password are not populating on the c# login method side as they are both null.

I've tried 3 different ways, for `HttpContext.Request`. Form it throws `null` error. I tried to parse the parameters in the method using the `[FromBody]` tag and get `null`. I also tried using a stream reader but it returns an empty string.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login([FromBody] string username, [FromBody] string password) // both are null
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The form has " + username.ToString());
   
    // throws null error
    //string bodyValues = HttpContext.Request.Form["username"];
    
    Stream req = Request.Body;
    //req.Position = 0;
    string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEndAsync().Result;

    string input = null;
    try
    {
        input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Try and handle malformed POST body
        return new  JsonResult("false");
    }

    return new JsonResult("true");
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix your javascript

```
function login(username, password) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: { username : username, password: password }
    };
......
```

and try to remove [FromBody] since you can not use it twice

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login( string username, string password)
```

if you still have some problems try to create view model

```
public class PasViewModel
    {
      public string Username { get; set; }
      public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

and  add FromBody to  action view model

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login( [FromBody] PasViewModel viewModel)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried the above but im still receiving null for username and string in the controller

Comment: What do you mean "receiving". Where are you receiving- in action or in javascript? I can't understand from your code what are your trying to send back to your javascript request?

Comment: For now I dont care about the login method response. I am just trying to get the username and password in the controller method to use them. I used the viewmodel approach there and still receiving null.

Comment: Try to add [FromBody] to viewmodel and let me know pls

Comment: Yea that was it thanks, if you add it to your answer ill accept it

Comment: @BryanTyrrell Thank you for feedback. It is hard to figure since fetch is using. I updated my answer.